# zipped folder without directory structure

Tags: structure

I'm trying to create a delivery package that pulls files from multiple locations and adds them to a dated folder, then zips the dated folder. What I'm getting is a zipped dated folder but it contains the entire directory structure from the root right up to the dated folder.

I've tried the solutions found here for what I assume are the same issues being experienced by other users but none seem to work for me. I'm very new to this and have been figuring things out as I go but this has me stumped.
Here's what I'm using

```
#Once all the files have been copied over zip them up.
zip_ready = 0   #default value

try:
    all_movie_files = os.listdir(delivery_dir)
    if len(all_movie_files) > 0:
        #First create a zip container
        zipname = '%s_delivery' % os.path.basename(delivery_dir)
        zip_file = os.path.join(delivery_dir,zipname)
        new_txt = ""
        for i in all_movie_files:
            zip_this = "/".join((delivery_dir,i))
            new_txt = new_txt+" "+zip_this
        zip_cmd = "zip "+zip_file+" "+new_txt
        server.log("debug","running cmd: %s" % zip_cmd)
        os.system(zip_cmd)
except Exception as e:
    msg = "ERROR creating zip file: %s" % str(e)
    server.log("error",msg)
else:
    #zip file was created
    zip_ready = 1
```

Comment: What language is this? It looks like Python, but if so, the indentation is wrong.

Comment: Hi, this is Python but when I pasted the code in to the question I got an error saying that I had to indent 4 spaces or something...so I did.

Comment: How does it look now?